# TSQL Searching Needle in Haystack

Tags: sql, t-sql

For example I have database A and I know that somewhere in one of those tables is field B with value C, however I have no idea of that field name nor table.

Question: What is the fastest way to detect (?) in what table and field is that value C ?

Comment: This may be useful - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11676778/16391. Rework at your leisure.

Comment: SSMS tools pack has functionality for this.

Comment: Thanks Martin! That is a good alternative I suppose, but what license do SSMS Tools have? (GPL?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this script long time ago, it has been very useful for reverse engineering

```
set nocount off

declare @searchvalue varchar(100)
set @searchvalue = 'text to find'


create table #tt (table_name varchar(64), column_name varchar(64), count int)
select * into #t from 
(
select 'select ''' + a.table_name + ''' ''table_name'',''' + a.column_name + ''' ''column_name'', count(*) count from [' + a.table_name +'] where [' +a.column_name+']='''+@searchvalue +'''' + ' group by ['+ a.column_name+']' sqlstring
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS a
join 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES b
on a.table_name = b.table_name
and b.table_type = 'base table'
 where data_type like '%char'
) a

--loop cursor
Declare @sqlstring as nvarchar(500)
Declare SqlCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT sqlstring FROM #t
OPEN SqlCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM SqlCursor
INTO @sqlstring
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
      -- do row specific stuff here
insert #tt
exec(@sqlstring)
     FETCH NEXT FROM SqlCursor
     INTO @sqlstring
END
CLOSE SqlCursor
DEALLOCATE SqlCursor
select * from #tt
drop table #tt
drop table #t
```

Comment: Finally I have enough reputation to give you one

Comment: @undefined glad to hear you enjoyed my script